# CakePHP: Custom Error reporting in Console Commands

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling

we're currently using CakePHP 2.4.7 and a custom error handler. The custom error handler works fine for every request made through HTTP or via CronDispatcher.

Unfortunately, when making a console request to one of our Console Commands, the error handler  is ignored.

See the following example:

**core.php:**

```
App::uses('SentryErrorHandler', 'Sentry.Lib');

Configure::write('Sentry', array(
  //'production_only' => true, // true is default value -> no error in sentry when debug
  'PHP' => array(
    'server' => 'https://XXX:YYY@app.getsentry.com/1234'
  )
));

Configure::write('Error', array(
  'handler' => 'SentryErrorHandler::handleError',
  'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED,
  'trace' => true
));

Configure::write('Exception', array(
  'handler' => 'SentryErrorHandler::handleException',
  'renderer' => 'ExceptionRenderer',
  'log' => true
));
```

**XYController.php / XYShell.php:**

```
function test() {
  die(pr([]['test']));
}
```

In both cases, the correct error is thrown:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /vagrant/htdocs/app/Console/Command/XYShell.php on line 50

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /vagrant/htdocs/app/Console/Command/XYShell.php on line 50
Fatal Error Error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in [/vagrant/htdocs/app/Console/Command/XYShell.php, line 50]
```

But when calling the mentioned method via ./cake XY test, it looks like, that the error is not properly propagated to the custom error handler.

Am I missing something?

Comment: ` or via CronDispatcher` not related to your question but "Oh god no...". There is no need for a cron dispatcher.

Comment: I know, we're replacing more and more of the cron dispatcher code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Console and web don't use the same config

The Exception and error config have [separate options](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html#error-configuration) to the standard exception and error config:

> consoleHandler - callback - The callback used to handle errors when running in the console. If undefined, CakePHP’s default handlers will be used.

This is also apparent [from the source](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.7/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php#L154-L178).

As such to configure a different handler to be used for *both* web and cli requests - define both the `handler` and `consoleHandler` keys:

```
Configure::write('Error', array(
  'handler' => 'SentryErrorHandler::handleError',
  'consoleHandler' => 'SentryErrorHandler::handleError', # <--
  'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED,
  'trace' => true
));

Configure::write('Exception', array(
  'handler' => 'SentryErrorHandler::handleException',
  'consoleHandler' => 'SentryErrorHandler::handleException', # <--
  'renderer' => 'ExceptionRenderer',
  'log' => true
));
```

Comment: when using the mentioned code, i'm running in a controller initializiation error. looks like, that the ExceptionRenderer is trying to send a http-response. in a console environment, I don't think, that the initialization of the controller does make sense at all.

is this a problem with SentryErrorHandler's code (https://github.com/justnom/cakephp-sentry/blob/master/Lib/SentryErrorHandler.php - because the class is not extending ConsoleErrorHandler)?

Comment: I don't use that plugin, I don't know what initilization error you mean. However it looks like [it is written to expect a web request](https://github.com/justnom/cakephp-sentry/blob/master/Lib/SentryErrorHandler.php#L53-L81), there won't be any user context for cli requests of course so it would probably be appropriate to create a ConsoleExceptionHandler [extending the core one](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleErrorHandler.php) - if it were me I'd PR that change =).

Comment: i already tried to PR this change based on the core ConsoleHandler, but I found another problem there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23656173/cakephp-how-to-implement-a-custom-consoleerrorhandler :/