# CakePHP: How to implement a custom ConsoleErrorHandler

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling

In relation to my last question [CakePHP: Custom Error reporting in Console Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635430/cakephp-custom-error-reporting-in-console-commands) I stumbled upon the next problem:

Because SentryErrroHandler::handleError does not work as a consoleHandler out of the box, I wanted to implement a new SentryConsoleErrorHandler on my own.

When extending ConsoleErrorHandler, I now have the problem, that ConsoleErrorHandler handleError/handleException methods are not defined as static methods.

So, in core.php, I've created a new instance of SentryConsoleErrorHandler. Unfortunately, it seems impossible to create a Plugin-class there? (`Uncaught exception 'MissingPluginException' with message 'Plugin Sentry could not be found.'`)

Here's my code:

**core.php:**

```
App::uses('SentryErrorHandler', 'Sentry.Lib');
App::uses('SentryConsoleErrorHandler', 'Sentry.Lib'); # <--

$consoleErrorHandler = new SentryConsoleErrorHandler(); # <--

Configure::write('Sentry', array(
  'production_only' => true, // true is default value -> no error in sentry when debug
  'PHP' => array(
    'server' => 'https://XXX:YYY@app.getsentry.com/1234'
  )
));

Configure::write('Error', array(
  'handler' => 'SentryErrorHandler::handleError',
  'consoleHandler' => [$consoleErrorHandler, 'handleError'], # <--
  'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED,
  'trace' => true
));
```

Is there any reason, why ConsoleErrorHandler has no static methods, and how is it possible to use a Plugin-Based Class as a ConsoleHandler, when the Plugin itself is loaded afterwards?

One thing I did not tried, because it feels wrong: Move the Configure::write('Error') code after the Plugin initialization.